# Is PCT (Partition Change Tracking) possible for list-range partitioned tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, materialized-views

I've created list-range partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE WHREST_PRT(
  RCNUM     NUMBER       NOT NULL,
  WHNUM     NUMBER       NOT NULL,
  WARE      VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  DATEM     DATE         NOT NULL,
  QUANTITY  NUMBER       NOT NULL,
  DATEOPER  DATE         NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST( RCNUM )  
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE( DATEM )( 
    PARTITION P127 VALUES (127) COMPRESS FOR OLTP ( 
        SUBPARTITION P127_PRE_2003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.01.2003','DD.MM.YYYY')) COMPRESS FOR OLTP, 
        SUBPARTITION P127_Q1_2003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.04.2003','DD.MM.YYYY')) COMPRESS FOR OLTP
    ),
    ...
    PARTITION P997 VALUES (997) COMPRESS FOR OLTP ( 
        SUBPARTITION P997_PRE_2003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.01.2003','DD.MM.YYYY')) COMPRESS FOR OLTP, 
        SUBPARTITION P997_Q1_2003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.04.2003','DD.MM.YYYY')) COMPRESS FOR OLTP 
    )
)
```

Then I manually added more quarter subpartitions (up to 01-JAN-2015) to each of 13 department partitions. Now the total number of subpartitons is 602.

Then filled it with data.

Now I'm trying to create materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_WHREST_SUM_QNT ( 
    RCNUM, WARE, DATEM, SUM_QNT, CNT_CNT, CNT 
) PARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT RCNUM, 
  WARE, 
  DATEM, 
  SUM( QUANTITY ),
  COUNT( QUANTITY ),
  COUNT( * )
FROM WHREST_PRT 
WHERE WHNUM > 1
GROUP BY RCNUM, WARE, DATEM
```

But results of DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW say that PCT is not possible with the following message:

```
2070    PCT not supported with this type of partitioning
```

I wonder why PCT is not possible in my case. Searching for that message together with 'list-range composite partitioning' resulted in nothing helpful.

Oracle version is 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bug.  Article ID 1281826.1 on My Oracle Support lists the types of partitioning that are eligible for Partition Change Tracking.  It doesn't explain why some partitioning type are not allowed.  Although it does include a reference to a bug for a different type of partitioning that is also not allowed.

Comment: From Oracle support (by ID you specified): "...only certain types of partitioned tables are eligible for PCT. The Oracle Datawarehousing Guide documentation (though version 11.2) does not currently contain the information about this restriction. 

The following types of partitioned tables are eligible for PCT in 10.1 through 11.2:

**-** Range partition with no sub-partition

**-** Range partition with List sub-partition

**-** Range partition with Hash sub-partition

**- List partition with no sub-partition**"

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a couple of things:

1. shift the DATEM to be the second column of the group by clause
2. remove the WHNUM predicate.
3. Add the DBMS_MVIEW.PMARKER column

Unlikely to work to be honest, but I'd give them a punt to see if you've hit something undocumented.